# Neo Euler won't display greek letters

Tags: fonts, xetex, unicode, euler

I'm trying to use the Neo Euler math font in a document, compiled using XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Palatino LT Std}
\setmathfont{Neo Euler}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{align*}
    F(\lambda) = \sum_{u = -\infty}^{\infty}a_{u}\exp (i2\pi \lambda u)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

However, it won't display the greek letters Pi and Lambda. Instead I get:

[image: Greek letters not showing]

Setting the main font to Palatino works as evident from the blind text. I downloaded the `euler.otf`from https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf and copied it into my `/Library/Fonts/` directory (I'm on OS X 10.9).

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, Neo Euler doesn't cover Greek letters.

Comment: I don’t know why the macros for Greek letters aren’t working, but typing the Greek letters directly does work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have only upright greek letters:

```
\setmathfont[math-style=upright,vargreek-shape=unicode]{Neo Euler}
```

Comment: That works, thanks! Is this a limitation of the Neo Euler font?

Comment: yes, Neo Euler isn't really complete

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Euler for the upright math letters only, which you might want to do in ISO style, that is also possible.  Here is an example that sets Euler’s identities in ISO style, in XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[
  Scale=1.0,
  Ligatures={Common, Discretionary, TeX}]
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range={up/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek},
                    bfup/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek},
                    cal, bfcal, frak, bffrak},
              script-features={},
              sscript-features={}
            ]{Neo Euler}

\newcommand\upi{\symup{i}}
\newcommand\upe{\symup{e}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \upe^{\upi x} &= \cos{x} + \upi \sin{x} \\
  \upe^{\upi \uppi} + 1 &= 0
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: The Euler identities]

Here, everything except for the upright and bold-upright letters is taken from Asana Math (which is based on `newpx`.)  The operator names are, by default, taken from the text font, which is another Palatino clone.

In particular, you will notice that the imaginary unit i is set in Neo Euler, but the i in sin and the digits are in Palatino, and the variable *x* is an italic Palatino.

If you want to use more of Neo Euler, you can add it to the `range=` list.  As it is incomplete and no longer being updated, you would want to load another math font before it, as a fallback for symbols it does not contain.  The complete set of symbols in Neo Euler is:

```
\setmathfont[range={"0000-"0001,"0020-"007E,
                    "00A0,"00A7-"00A8,"00AC,"00AF,"00B1,"00B4-"00B5,"00B7,
                    "00D7,"00F7,
                    "0131,
                    "0237,"02C6-"02C7,"02D8-"02DA,"02DC,
                    "0300-"030C,"030F,"0311,"0323-"0325,"032E-"0332,"0338,
                    "0391-"0393,"0395-"03A1,"03A3-"03A8,"03B1-"03BB,
                    "03BD-"03C1,"03C3-"03C9,"03D1,"03D5-"03D6,"03F5,
                    "2016,"2018-"2019,"2021,"2026-"202C,"2032-"2037,"2044,
                    "2057,"20D6-"20D7,"20DB-"20DD,"20E1,"20EE-"20EF,
                    "210B-"210C,"210E-"2113,"2118,"211B-"211C,"2126-"2128,
                    "212C-"212D,"2130-"2131,"2133,"2135,"2190-"2199,
                    "21A4,"21A6,"21A9-"21AA,"21BC-"21CC,"21D0-"21D5,
                    "2200,"2202-"2209,"220B-"220C,"220F-"2213,"2215-"221E,
                    "2223,"2225,"2227-"222E,"2234-"2235,"2237-"223D,
                    "2240-"224C,"2260-"2269,"226E-"2279,"2282-"228B,"228E,
                    "2291-"2292,"2295-"2299,"22A2-"22A5,"22C0-"22C5,
                    "22DC-"22DD,"22EF,"22F0-"22F1,
                    "2308-"230B,"2320-"2321,"2329-"232A,"239B-"23AE,
                    "23DC-"23DF,
                    "27E8-"27E9,"27F5-"27FE,"2A0C,"2B1A,
                    "1D400-"1D433,"1D49C,"1D49E-"1D49F,"1D4A2,"1D4A5-"1D4A6,
                    "1D4A9-"1D4AC,"1D4AE-"1D4B5,"1D4D0-"1D4E9,"1D504-"1D505,
                    "1D507-"1D50A,"1D50D-"1D514,"1D516-"1D51C,"1D51E-"1D537,
                    "1D56C-"1D59F,"1D6A8-"1D6B8,"1D6BA-"1D6D2,"1D6D4-"1D6DD,
                    "1D6DF,"1D6E1,"1D7CE-"1D7D7
                   }]{Neo Euler}
```

A version of that sample compatible with PDFLaTeX is:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since 2018
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newpxtext, newpxmath}
% If you also want to load Euler Script and Fraktur, you want mathalfa.

\DeclareSymbolFont{eulerup}{U}{zeur}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\uppi}{\mathalpha}{eulerup}{"19}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upi}{\mathalpha}{eulerup}{"69}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upe}{\mathalpha}{eulerup}{"65}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \upe^{\upi x} &= \cos{x} + \upi \sin{x} \\
  \upe^{\upi \uppi} + 1 &= 0
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

You would need to create any additional constants such as `\uppi` yourself.  The font table is given in the `amsfonts` documentation, but it is the same as OML.

A simple alternative for Euler math with either Palatino (newpx) or Optima (URW Classico) text is the `eulerpx` package.